# How can I achieve this result in c++? Arrays pointing to arrays

Tags: python, c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to do the following operations using c/c++.
In order to explain how the code should work, I've written this example python code.

```
A=[1,2]
B=[3,4]
C=[5,6]

X=[A,B,C]

print(X[2][1]) ##this should print the second element of the third array (6)
```

When in python I create a list of precedently created list, it's just like defining a bidimensional array(obviously without the possibility to call by name each sub-array).

In c/c++ I'm not able to do this. I read on the internet that when I point to an array, I will always get the first element, is it true?

I'm able to create a bidimensional array in c++, but i need to define first each array (A,B,C) and then list all of them in the big array X.
How can I achieve this task?

Comment: So does the pythin code do what you want to do in C++, or not?  I am confused, there is a paragraph where you talked about not making the sub-arrays first.  The python code makes the sub-arrays first.

Comment: The python code does exactly what I want. Sorry I'm italian, it's not easy for me ti explain my thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
int A[]={1,2};
int B[]={3,4};
int C[]={5,6};
int* X[]={A,B,C};
printf("%d\n",X[2][1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) for this job.

```
int A[]={1,2};
int B[]={3,4};
int C[]={5,6};
std::vector<int> a(A,A+1);
std::vector<int> b(B,B+1);
std::vector<int> c(C,C+1);
std::vector<std::vector<int> > x;
x.push_back(a); x.push_back(b); x.push_back(c);
printf("%d\n",x[2][1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm using Arduino, so this operations are not avaiable on this platform (I think). And I'm also quite a newbie in c++, I always used python And this kind of solution is not so easy for me ti understand, however I'll keep your answer and I will study it when I'll learn better c++. Thanks a lot.